# AngularJS - ng-repeat multidimensional array

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know there are already a lot questions about this topic which got answered.

Im new to Angular and haven't understood how the `{{variable}}` thing exactly works.

Im using an API and the respond is something like that:

```
data : "MTS-K"
license : "CC BY 4.0 -  https://creativecommons.de"
ok : true
stations : Array(3)
0 : {id: "XXX", name: "XXX", brand: "XXX", street: "XXX", place: "YYY"}
1 : {id: "XXX", name: "XXX", brand: "XXX", street: "XXX", place: "YYY"}
2 : {id: "XXX", name: "XXX", brand: "XXX", street: "XXX", place: "YYY"}
__proto__ : Object
```

My ts to get this data looks like this:

```
this.GasStationProvider.getStations(this.location.lat, this.location.lng).subscribe(
gasStation => {
    this.gasStation = gasStation.stations;
});
```

and my HTML like this:

```
<p>{{gasStation.stations}}</p>
```

the rendered HTML like this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Could you help me how I can display every "line" in the station array? Or just send me a link to a good tutorial if you know one.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is it angular 1 that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat` to iterate through `array of objects` and also to iterate `each field of the object`.

```
/*First loop will iterate over all objects of gasStation*/

<p ng-repeat="station in gasStation">//iterating the stations array

  //this 2nd loop will iterate over the objects field: {id: "XXX", name: "XXX",..}

  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in station">//iterating over each field in the object.
    {{key}} : {{value}}
  </li>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're using TypeScript, you're using Angular 2+ and not AngularJS.
Therefore, *ngFor is the right use for this and not ng-repeat.

It works like an iterator in a for loop:

```
//pseudocode

for( item in array )
   //using interpolation
   {{ item.value }}
```

So, if you're getting Object object, you might want to try going a step further and trying to output a value in your array, like

```
<p>
    {{gasStation.stations.name}}
</p>
```

Another tip is to console.log your object so you can see how it's coming through.